# Excel: Applying Condittional formatting to every other row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office, worksheet-function

I would like to apply a specific conditional format to every second row in my spreadsheet. In my specific case I have regression results, where the first row indicates the beta coefficient and the second row the p-value. I would like to highlight the second row, where the p-value is between 0 and 0.05 as well as where it is between 0.05 and 0.1.

What I tried is using a filter to hide the first row, then highlight the remaining cells and applying the conditional format. Once I remove the filter, the rule is applied to the entire selection, however. Is there any other way to do this?

EDIT: The conditions I intend to apply are:

1. If cell value between 0 and 0.05, then shade green
2. If cell value between 0.05 and 0.1, then shade yellow

Comment: Could you put your current condition in your question so that we have a better idea of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try two rules:

```
=AND(ISODD(ROW()),A1>0,A1<0.05)  
=AND(ISODD(ROW()),A1>0.05,A1<0.1)
```

Choose Applies to to suit, add some `=`s if required and change `ODD` to `EVEN` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only applying to every other row, apply it to every row and test if it's a row you want...  I assume you will not be resorting the data and there is no label we can test (which would be better, as testing by row number is vulnerable to re-sorts:

```
=AND(MOD(ROW(D1),2)=0,D1>=0,D1<=0.05)
```